# Trying to display a list of posts via category

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a page in which a user selects a category (the button below represents one category), and a list of posts in that category are displayed, via the while loop, however when the button is clicked nothing is happening and I can't figure out why..

```
<div id = "cat_container">
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
  <table valign="top">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="get">
          <input type="button" name="button" value="<?php echo $row["cat_name"];?>"></button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php
}
?>
</div>

<div id="post_container" >
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['button'])) {

        $category = $_GET['button'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_cat` = '$category'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row["post_content"];?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: PHP code is only ran once on the server side, to respond to user input you would need to add some javascript or reload the page.

Comment: You need to use either form or Ajax for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the form is not being submitted because of "button" input type. Try to change it to "submit" and remove redundant `</button>` tag after it.

```
          <input type="submit" name="button" value="<?php echo $row["cat_name"];?>">
```